# Is there a way to retroactively set a TabBarItem's icon to a system item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I know you can init a TabBarItem in Objective-C with initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:, but is there a way to set the icon after you've created the TabBarItem? For instance:

```
self.tabBarItem.title = "@Browser";
self.tabBarItem.image =
```

Since the list of pre-defined system icons is an enum, I'm not sure how to insert them, because the image property looks for an object of type UIImage *.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it is not possible.  Judging from this quote "This method returns a system-supplied tab bar item. The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later." for `initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:`.  I'm willing to bet that it is returning a custom subclass of `UITabBarItem` that you don't have access to that does the drawing completely on its own.

Comment: Seems this way to me too. Simplest thing would be to grab images for the system items you want and just set your items with those.